# Why does cURL output "Request didn't contain valid JSON?"

Tags: json, curl

I looked everywhere for an answer, but couldn't find it.

I'm trying to run the following cURL command to the [Kippt API](https://github.com/kippt/api-documentation): `curl -k --user xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "{"title":"Meteor.js","is_private":false}" https://kippt.com/api/lists`.

This returns: `"message": "Request didn't contain valid JSON."`. Maybe it's something wrong with the command itself, maybe with the interaction with the Kippt API, but whatever it is, I can't seem to run this command.

Why does this happen, and how can I get around it?

**P. S.** It should be noted that I need this for a rather awkward Ruby-based resources-file parser thingie, and I can't use a file to hold the JSON. It has to be used raw in the cURL command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to escape your quotation marks?

```
curl -k --user xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "{\"title\":\"Meteor.js\",\"is_private\":false}" https://kippt.com/api/lists
```

Comment: Oh, jeez. I must be more tired than I thought. It works now. s-:

Thanks!